# AJAX post to php not getting caught

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Posting from javascript ajax (which according to alerts it hits correctly and succeeds at) I cannot get the post from my PHP code.

```
<script>
function SavePlot() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'PhpToR.php',
        data:{action:'SavePlot'},
        success:function() {
            alert("gets here");
        }

    });
}
</script>
```

So above it reaches the gets here alert, so it should be posting, however it isnt caught by the below php:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'SavePlot') {
    echo '<script>alert("Doesnt get here")</script>';
}
```

I've tried many other answers but couldn't seem to succeed.

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: Unsure what you're expecting. You don't do anything with the JS that's (theoretically) being returned to jquery. It doesn't randomly run stuff from a response...

Comment: Your ajax request is working, but you are not catching the response given by the server.

Comment: For watching it I looked at it in browser dev tools and it seemed fine on the js side. jQuery is included yes. No errors reported. Running this using Xampp through localhost.

Comment: It should be caught by what I have in PHP, I don't see how it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, whatever you echo in your php script won't show up automatically in your current HTML DOM.

However, you can retrieve what you've echo-ed in the PHP in your AJAX call:

```
success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
    alert("gets here");
}
```

In your console, you should see:

```
<script>alert("Doesnt get here")</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying `dataType` as `HTML` in your ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: 'PhpToR.php',
    data:{action:'SavePlot'},
    dataType : 'HTML',
    success:function() {
        alert("gets here");
    }

});
```